# Equivalence of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

We have the complex number:
$$ z = \frac{(1+i)^n}{(1-i)^{n-2}}$$
Having $n \in Z, n\ge 2$

I am asked for obtaining an equivalent of $z$ and selecting one of the provided 4 options.

Once I computed several algebraic steps I reached the outcome: $-2i^{n+1}$

The four options are:

a) $-2i$ if n is even and $-2$ if n is odd.

b) $-2(-1)^ni$.

c) $-2i(-1)^{n/2}$ is n is even and $2(-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$ if n is odd.

d) $2(-1)^{n+1}$

My issue is that I do not know how to interpret $-2i^{n+1}$ in order to select one of these 4. Could you help me out?

Comment: The correct option seems to be "c" but maybe there is a typo here: c) $-2i(-1)^{n/2}$ is n is even and $2(-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\color{red}i$ if n is odd.

Comment: @gimusi -- No, the $i$ doesn't belong. If $n$ is odd, then $n+1$ is even, so $-2i^{n+1}$ is Real.

Comment: Notice that (a), (b), and (d) give incorrect results when plugging in $n=2$. This narrows things down, so you just need a closer look at (c) to see how it's equivalent to your expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that

$$z = \frac{(1+i)^n}{(1-i)^{n-2}}= (1+i)^2\frac{(1+i)^{n-2}}{(1-i)^{n-2}}= (2i)\left(\frac{1+i}{1-i}\frac{1+i}{1+i}\right)^{n-2}= (2i)\left(\frac{2i}{2}\right)^{n-2}=2(i)^{n-1}$$

and $2(i)^{n-1}$is equal to $-2i(-1)^{n/2}$ is n is even and $2(-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$ if n is odd, indeed

- for $n=3 \implies 2(i)^{2}=-2$
- for $n=5 \implies 2(i)^{4}=2$
- for $n=7 \implies 2(i)^{6}=-2$
- ...

and

- for $n=2 \implies 2(i)=2i$
- for $n=4 \implies 2(i)^{3}=-2i$
- for $n=6 \implies 2(i)^{5}=2i$
- ...

or as an alternative

- for $n$ even $2i^{n-1}=2i^{2k-1} = 2i(-1)^{k-1}$

and

- for $n$ odd $2i^{n-1}=2i^{2k} = 2(-1)^k$

Comment: @gimsi I do not see how you obtained $\frac{(1+i)^{n-2}}{(1-i)^{n-2}}(1+i)^2$ . Could you add the previous algebraic steps?

Comment: @JD_PM We are simply factored $$(1+i)^{n}=(1+i)^{2}(1+i)^{n-2}$$

Comment: Ups my bad thanks

Comment: @JD_PM You are welcome! Feel free to ask for any other clarification.

Comment: @ gimsi Okey I agree with your answer, it must be a typo. But one last thing. The answer I got I think it is not wrong, it is just that I took a different path. Could I look for the equivalent? Or better if I start from scratch taking another path?

Comment: @JD_PM Yes of course your answer is correct and equivalent since $-2i^{n+1}=-2i^2i^{n-1}=2i^{n-1}$ but also directly from the expression you have found $-2i^{n+1}$ we can derive the correct answer with the same methods shown here.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that

$$\frac{1+i}{1-i}=i\implies\frac{(1+i)^n}{(1-i)^{n-2}}=\left(\frac{1+i}{1-i}\right)^{n-2}(1+i)^2=i^{n-2}2i\ldots$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $\displaystyle{1\over 1-i} = {1+i\over 2}$ we have:

$${(1+i)^n\over (1-i)^{n-2}} = {(1+i)^{2n-2}\over 2^{n-2}}={(2i)^{n-1}\over 2^{n-2}}=2i^{n-1}=...$$

Answer (score 2):

Upon doing the following operation
$$\frac{(1+i)}{(1-i)}= \frac{(1+i)(1+i)}{(1-i)(1+i)} = \frac{1 + 2i - 1}{1 + 1} = i$$
So
$$\frac{(1+i)^n}{(1-i)^{n-2}} = \frac{(1+i)^{n-2}}{(1-i)^{n-2}}(1+i)^2 = i^{n-2}(1+i)^2 = i^{n-2}(1 + 2i - 1) = i^{n-2}(2i) = 2i^{n-1}$$

Comment: We have that $$2i^{n-1}=2i^{2k} = 2(-1)^k$$ and $$2i^{n-1}=2i^{2k+1} = 2i^{2k}i = 2i(-1)^k$$ therefore the correct option is not "a". It seems to be "c" but with a typo.

Comment: Oh yeah haha thanks ..